# Execute Stored Procedure in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures

I'm trying to run SQL Server 2019 stored procedures in ASP.NET Core 3.1 but can't get them to run properly.

I have the repository layout pattern implemented and got the database objects with the command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server="";Database="";User ID="";Password="";" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir database
```

When executing the procedure, if the result is that the user exists in the database, it should return a 1, otherwise a 0. The problem that always returns a 1 to the variable "exists", but I suppose that I am not executing the stored procedure (it has an output parameter) or I don't know if the procedure needs to be imported into the application in some way.

Example of the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[LOGIN]
    @LOGIN    VARCHAR(50),  
    @PASSWORD VARCHAR(50),
    @EXIT     INT OUTPUT
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT USER_APP FROM USERS 
               WHERE USER_APP = @LOGIN AND PASSWORD = @PASSWORD)
    BEGIN
        SET @EXIT = 1
        RETURN @EXIT
    END

    SET @EXIT = 0
    RETURN @EXIT
END
```

Program:

```
private readonly dbContext _context;

public UsuariosRepository(dbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public async Task<bool> lOG(string user, string password)
{ 
    try
    {
        int exists= await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("EXECUTE Login {0},{1}", user, password);

        return exists > 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Update the question with the code I currently have according to the tutorial I found in:

https://erikej.github.io/efcore/2020/11/02/ef-core-sproc-return-value.html

```
var retcode = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "0",
    SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
    Value=0
};
var result =  _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("EXEC Login {0},{1},{2}", usuario, password,retcode);

int returnValue = (int)retcode.Value;
```

Even with the changes made it does not work for me, it displays the following error.

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Int32
```

[image: Error]

Thank you very much for your help.

**Tutorial**
[image: Tutorial image]

Comment: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx

Comment: I did a test with those commands, but it indicates that they are deprecated in NetCore 3.1. Thanks

Comment: Another Inconsistency I have found, in your `store procedure` you have `RETURN` it shouldn't return anything because within `store procedure` we have to use `SELECT` statement, I doubt your `sp` can return `1` or `0` in this fashion, another thing is you have defined 3 parameter but passing 2 argument which should thrown a expection, I think as per your scenario you should write `DECLARE  @EXIT INT` inside the `sp` body rather define it.

Comment: There are 3 ways to return info from a sproc: RETURN a value - should only be used to indicate status of the operation and **not** to return business logic like "user does/doesn't exist", OUTPUT parameter to send a single value or set of values, SELECT a resultset. You're using the wrong one..

Comment: Additionally `int exists= await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("EXECUTE Login {0},{1}", user, password);` always would return `-1` in this fashion

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron The stored procedure I am not allowed to modify it. I have to join the company. I just updated the question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @CaiusJard Update the question according to a tutorial I found. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Aside: Please tell your new company to stop storing passwords in plain text!

Comment: So far I have investigated, if you don't modify the `Store Procedure` you cannot make it work for sure.

Comment: Your casting exception is very obvious, you don't have any key returned from your sp to it cannot parse into relevant value, even you cannot convert the value due to the absence of key

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Could you help me by telling me how the code should be, I don't have much experience with ASP.NET Core. Thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: You have to modify the sp `LOGIN` no other way you have left! You may look forward to work around but none of them can resolve your main problem rather bring you into another issue. If you are willing to modify then I can guide you through

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron If I better change the sproc, please tell me how to proceed, thank you.

Comment: I don't see why the sproc *must* change... While not ideal, it can be used as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use your sproc as-is, you should probably hook up to the output parameter. Note, that this doesn't really use* EF Core for anything more than "something that generates a SqlConnection/command":

```
string user = "bob";
string password = Convert.ToBase64tring(Sha256Hash("secret", "mmmmsalty"));// you salt and hash your passwords, right??


using var cmd = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[LOGIN]";

//common
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) cmd.Connection.Open();
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LOGIN", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = user });
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PASSWORD", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = password });
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EXIT", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

var userExists = (int)cmd.Parameters["@EXIT"].Value == 1;
```

Remember to add necessary `using`s..

<sub>* (AFAIA, no method does; even methods that look like they use EF Core just grab its SQLBuilder and build a comamnd that calls the sproc)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteSqlRawAsync` returns the number of rows affected for inserts, updates and deletes (-1 for selects).

I'd recommend you alter your SP to remove the output parameter and instead use `SqlCommand. SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` to return the first column of the first row in the result set:

```
using (var cmd = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[LOGIN]";
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    if (cmd.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("LOGIN", user));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("PASSWORD", password));
    exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Simply declare the @EXIT not as an Output, eg:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[LOGIN]
    @LOGIN      VARCHAR(50),    
    @PASSWORD   VARCHAR(50) 

    DECLARE @EXIT INT
```

And replace CREATE with ALTER to edit the Stored Procedure.